# It is possible to use <0></0> in xml?

Tags: xml, string

I'm trying to build an XML file (which will be converted to JSON later on).

Therefore I must respect a schema, and i need to put <0> and <1> in the XML but it doesn't work. I also try to put <\0> and <\1> but it says that it's not a good char for XML.

```
<Result>
    <Content>
        <0></0>
        <1></1>
    </Content>
</Result>
```

In the debugger in Visual Studio I put a break point in the aim to see the xml, but with <0> i can't open the document as a XML, only as Text.

How can I fix that?

Comment: You will need to change the JSON schema, or fix this up during / after conversion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is impossible. XML element names [must start with a letter or underscore](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp) .

Comment: I will change the shema to avoid <0>

Answer (score 2):

It's possible, but you have to use the `CDATA` tag, but that means that they're not actually XML elements though. This technique is used when putting HTML in an XML file.

```
<Result>
    <Content>
        <![CDATA[
            <0>
           </0>
           <1>
          </1>
       ]]>
    </Content>
</Result>
```